# Apache maven installation issue

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have installed Maven 3.3.1 on XP - and it seems to have gone fine.
However,when I do a mvn --version thereafter - I get the strange response below:

```
C:\>mvn --version
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
......
```

Would appreciate help in getting through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven command file runs JVM with arguments. What java version do you have?
JDK     **Maven 3.3** requires **JDK 1.7 or** above, Maven 3.2 requires JDK 1.6 or above, while Maven 3.0/3.1 requires JDK 1.5 or above

Comment: See the Release Notes: http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/